# How do you display empty rows in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a spreadsheet with a column populated with elements from a list of possible options. Take this simple example in Excel:

[image]

The 'Fruit' column contains data from the 'Types of fruit' column. The frequency of each fruit type is shown and is easy to calculate in Excel.

When I import the data into Tableau with 'Fruit' as the column dimension and 'Number of Records' as the measure, it doesn't display the fruit types that do not occur at all.

[image]

Is there a way of generating a table in Tableau that has all the types of fruit in the rows and the respective frequencies in the column?

Comment: What happens when you put Fruit Types in the view?

Comment: It displays '1' next to each fruit type

Comment: That's because you are counting records. Replace `Number of Records` with `Occurrence`

Comment: I would like to do it without using the 'Occurence' column from Excel. i.e. I want to create the 'Occurence' column in Tableau.

Comment: What would the new `Occurrence` column consist of? What is your calculation?

Comment: It would be equivalent to the 'Occurrence' column in Excel

Comment: I'm confused. If you want what you see in that Excel sample, very simply add the `Types of Fruit` field to your view.

Answer (score -1):

You need to put Fruit and Types Of Fruit on seperate sheets in Excel and then left join on Types of Fruit when you import into Tableau:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNnpu.jpg

You can then add Types of Fruit to the view and cnt(Fruit).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pj7vH.jpg